# Why is the key in Data.Map constrained to class Ord?

Tags: haskell, deriving

Suppose I define a simple type like this:

```
data Object = House | Table | Book
```

To be able to use `Object`s as keys for a map, the type has to be derived from `Eq` and `Ord`:

```
data Object = House | Table | Book deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

What is the reason for this restriction? Why do the keys of a map need to be orderable?

Comment: I imagine it's because the implementation uses balanced binary trees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Data.Map` offers O(log N) complexity on most operations (insertion, lookup, deletion, ...). It can do that since internally it uses a balanced search tree. That, in turn, requires an ordering relation on keys, hence the `Ord` constraint. `Eq` is a superclass of `Ord`, so that must be provided as well.

With only `Eq` we can't be as efficient on -say- lookup, since the best we can do in such case is to perform a linear search, which is O(N).

Without `Eq`, we can not perform lookup at all since we have no way to compare already inserted keys with the key to look up.